# add an extra byte in tcp-ack packet

Tags: tcp

i am working on improving the performance of TCP protocol over mobile ad-hoc network.
i need to add an extra byte in TCP-ACK packet.
can anyone suggest how to do that and how to let the kernel use my redesigned TCP packet?

Comment: Have you checked with the people working in this area? Creating a TCP that doesn't interoperate with standard TCP doesn't even qualify for "bad idea"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a crazy idea because you have to write your own layer-4 stack (both client-server sides) but you can do it using [Raw Sockets](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw). Infact you'll be able to forge your own packets encapsuled on `network-layer` (`IP`) or even work at a lower level.